# Formal specification of simple graph

Tags: graph-theory

Given a list of three vertices and a list of seven edges, show that  $ 3^7 $ different formal specifications for simple graphs are possible.

This seems a simple  question but in the book(Graph theory and its applications by Jonathan L. Gross, Jay Yellen and Mark Anderson) in which i found it, no definition is given on how can there be more than one formal specification for a simple graph or what makes two formal specifications different.

DEFINITION:
A formal specification of a simple graph is given by an adjacent table with a row for each vertex, containing the list of neighbors of that vertex.

And my doubts do not end here. What are the edges here for? I mean in the formal specification definition there isn't anything about them.
Does it just mean i can connect all my vertexes?

To solve this tried different interpretations, for example i considered that a formal specification is different if there is at least one vertex that differs(could be a row or just a vertex in an adjacent list).

But this does not take me to anywhere close to $ 3^7 $.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure about the numbers of vertices and edges? A simple graph with $n$ vertices cannot have more than $\frac12 n(n-1)$  edges.

Comment: @MarcOlschok I am sure the question is as stated.

Comment: The only way in which I can arrive at $3^7$ is in the case of multigraphs without loops, i.e. where the graph is given by a set $V$ of vertices, a set $E$ of edges and a map $\partial : E\to \binom{V}2 $, which (unlike in the case of simple graphs) is not required to be injective. Then for $|V|=3$ and $|E|=7$ we have $\binom{3}{2}=3$ and hence $3^7$ possibilities for such a map.

Comment: Meanwhile I have seen the book in a library. Your recollection is correct. It is a mistake in the exercise. It only makes sense for general graphs where you use the formal specification via the incidence table. Then it works as outlined in my previous comment.